# Weird segue transition after disabling autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, segue

I don't know how to explain this, it's really strange.

Ok think about two view controllers, the first one is a tableview controller and has a button in his navigation bar connected via push segue to the second view controller.
When pushing the button, the second view controller comes in from the right and at the same time pushes the first view controller out, to the left.

I wasn't using auto layout for my project but I've activated it to test something (I've just activated two constraints for two labels in the prototype cell). Then I've disabled the auto layout and now when I push the button on the first controller the second one comes in, but instead of pushing out the first controller, it slides on the back of the first one, that disappears only when the animation ends.

It's like if all the cells in my first controller become transparent during the transition.

I can't see anything strange in my settings so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you try a Clean, then build yet? That's always a great place to start with ghost configuration issues. Otherwise, are there several nib files involved? do any of them still have the "Use Autolayout" box checked?

Comment: I tried a Clean but it didn't solve the problem. I'm using IB and the only problem is with these two views. No views have the Use Autolayout box checked.

Comment: Not gonna lie, this sounds like one of those annoying problems where you dig around for 30 minutes with no success, and then suddenly find something in IB that fixes it with a single click. I hope you can find it faster, but if not, I feel your pain.

Comment: @Aleph72: maybe it's a good time to start using a version control system.

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko I do on all my new projects, but this is a very old one that I was modifying.

Comment: @Aleph72: maybe xml became corrupted. Have you tried recreating segues, changing their settings, etc.?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko Yes, tens of times... I've also tried to delete the table view controller and replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as Ryan said, it was one of those annoying problems where you dig around for 30 (for me it's been 90) minutes with no success and then find out how to fix it with a single click.
It turns out that the second view controller had a transparent background (don't know why), so reverting it to white solved the problem.

Thanks God I din't delete the storyboard to make it ex-novo.